# Cursor Window is full - out of memory

Tags: android, database, cursor

I am getting cursor window is full error. I have spent a long time looking at similar questions raised and documentation. I expect that two of my db helper class methods are trying to get the cursor to do too much.

One of my methods on my UI thread was calling my db helper methods, so I changed that to an AsyncTask - but no change. Then I thought it was because I wasn't closing my cursors after use - so I add closes to the finally statements - but still no change - I also closed db just in case that was impacting.

My two db helper methods:

```
public List<List<String>> getAllAnswersByQuestion1() {
    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
    List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    array1.clear();
    array2.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS + " ta, "
            + TABLE_QUESTION + " tq WHERE  ta." + ASID
            + " = " + "tq." + ASID;

   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

   try {

   if (c.moveToNext())
   {
       do {

     String questdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(QDESCR));
     String answerSetIds = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ASID));
     array1.add(questdescr);
     array2.add(answerSetIds);


    } while (c.moveToNext());

 }
   List< List<String> > listArray = new ArrayList< List<String> >();
   listArray.add(array1);
   listArray.add(array2);

   return listArray;

} finally {
    if (c!=null) {
        c.close();

    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    }
}

}

public List<List<String>> getAnswers(String answerId) {


    List<String> array1 = new ArrayList<String>();    
    List<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();  

    array1.clear();
    array2.clear();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] columns = new String[]{TDESCR, ADESCR};
    String selection = ASID+"=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(answerId)};
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_ANSWERS, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    try {

   if (c.moveToNext())       
   {
    do {

     String textdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TDESCR));
     String answersdescr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ADESCR));
     array1.add(textdescr);
     array2.add(answersdescr);;

    } while (c.moveToNext());

 }
   List< List<String> > listArray2 = new ArrayList< List<String> >();
   listArray2.add(array1);
   listArray2.add(array2);

   return listArray2;

    } finally {
        if (c!=null) {
            c.close();

        if (db != null)
            db.close();
        }

}
}
```

I also tried a bit of code to help identify memory leaks, but it didn't seem to work. Here is my logcat:

```
05-24 16:56:34.729: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 86903K/87112K, paused 194ms, total 194ms
05-24 16:56:36.689: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 5 bytes, free space 4 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:38.679: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 2 bytes, free space 0 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:40.789: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 79 bytes, free space 26 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:42.889: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 132 bytes, free space 22 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:44.949: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 64 bytes, free space 33 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:47.079: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 132 bytes, free space 81 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:47.309: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 101.059MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:47.309: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 1% free 95089K/95300K, paused 222ms, total 222ms
05-24 16:56:49.499: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 132 bytes, free space 129 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:51.809: W/CursorWindow(26305): Window is full: requested allocation 79 bytes, free space 28 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
05-24 16:56:52.049: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:52.049: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 98095K/98304K, paused 224ms, total 224ms
05-24 16:56:52.269: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:52.269: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 98095K/98304K, paused 224ms, total 225ms
05-24 16:56:52.269: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 168-byte allocation
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:52.529: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 121K, 1% free 97973K/98304K, paused 260ms, total 260ms
05-24 16:56:52.529: E/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Out of memory on a 168-byte allocation.
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm(26305): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41bc65e0 self=0x603ac400
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | sysTid=26842 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1614465112
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | state=R schedstat=( 68056904399 9638134962 38201 ) utm=6737 stm=68 core=1
05-24 16:56:52.529: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-24 16:56:52.539: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-24 16:56:52.539: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-24 16:56:52.549: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.SQLDatabaseHelper.getAllAnswersByQuestion1(SQLDatabaseHelper.java:392)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$showNextRandomQuestion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:394)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$showNextRandomQuestion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-24 16:56:52.559: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-24 16:56:52.779: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:52.779: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 97973K/98304K, paused 224ms, total 224ms
05-24 16:56:52.779: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 112-byte allocation
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Clamp target GC heap from 103.995MB to 96.000MB
05-24 16:56:53.039: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 97973K/98304K, paused 255ms, total 255ms
05-24 16:56:53.039: E/dalvikvm-heap(26305): Out of memory on a 112-byte allocation.
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=12 RUNNABLE
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41bc65e0 self=0x603ac400
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | sysTid=26842 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1614465112
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   | state=R schedstat=( 68538814034 9650804336 38242 ) utm=6781 stm=72 core=1
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Throwable.nativeFillInStackTrace(Native Method)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(Throwable.java:166)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:85)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Error.<init>(Error.java:37)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.VirtualMachineError.<init>(VirtualMachineError.java:35)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>(OutOfMemoryError.java:33)
05-24 16:56:53.039: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.SQLDatabaseHelper.getAllAnswersByQuestion1(SQLDatabaseHelper.java:392)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$showNextRandomQuestion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:394)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$showNextRandomQuestion.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-24 16:56:53.049: I/dalvikvm(26305):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-24 16:56:53.049: W/dalvikvm(26305): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;)
05-24 16:56:53.219: D/dalvikvm(26305): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77455K, 80% free 20518K/98304K, paused 169ms, total 169ms
05-24 16:56:53.219: W/dalvikvm(26305): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415aad88)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305): Process: com.example.quizapp, PID: 26305
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
05-24 16:56:53.229: E/AndroidRuntime(26305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Unfortunately I am not quite able to detect how best to improve my methods based on this logcat. Really could do with being pointed in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Comment: why do you iterate the Cursor in `getAllAnswersByQuestion1()` and `getAnswers()`?

Comment: Are you saying that is not good practice basically?. This how I have learnt to do it - so do you think they should be initiated in the main activity methods that use the returned arrays from these two dp helper class methods? Honestly, if I should be doing it a different way then please let me know.

Comment: just return the Cursor and use it as you wish: there is no need to duplicate Cursor data

Comment: But how would that look like in the code, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: cursor.moveToPosition(); cursor.get*();

Comment: Thanks. Admittedly I'll have to look at where in my code I put this and what it replaces. Do you think this will resolve my cursor window full issue though?

Comment: @pskink - Just wanted to find out more from you. The reason I am iterating it twice in each method is that both methods will return different db query results - and within each method I thought I'd have to move through every row from the first - rather than ever go to an absolute position (cursor.moveToPosition). You think differently? Cheers again - much appreciated.

Comment: try to  change  if (c.moveToNext())  to  if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())